# how to store and query based on daterange/age?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm building a commission calculator, and I'm not sure how to proceed.  I have situations like: saleRep A for customer 123 gets 2% for the first 2 years, then .5% thereafter.  I already know how to get the age of the customer.

And the date ranges are variable.  Meaning that one salesRep/Customer combination could split at 1 year, 2 years, anytime, but probably on the year.

So, how do I query for and store this?  My commission table is currently as follows, do I need to change it?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NCL_Commissions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductType] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LowCost] [int] NULL,
    [HighCost] [int] NULL,
    [CustCode] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [SalesRep] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Commission] [float] NULL,
    [MinAge] [smallint] NULL,
    [MaxAge] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NCL_Commissions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here's how I built it when I was told all commissions would be the same:

```
  DECLARE @custCreationDate datetime

    SET @custCreationDate = (   SELECT TOP 1 cast(INVDate as datetime)
                                FROM InvoiceHeader
                                WHERE companycode = @custCode
                                order by recid asc      )

--  PRINT 'Line 54: @custCreationDate: ' + cast(@custCreationDate as varchar)

    --If the customer has existed for less than a year
    IF @custCreationDate > DateAdd(yy, -1, @now)
        BEGIN
            SET @result = 2.00  --Customers in existance for less than a year yeild 2% commission
--          PRINT 'Line 60 - @result: ' + cast(@result as varchar)
            GOTO Exit_Function
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @result = 0.50  --Customers in existance longer yeild 0.5 % commission.
--          PRINT 'Line 66 - @result: ' + cast(@result as varchar)
            GOTO Exit_Function
        END
```

Sample Data (part of question is looking for suggestions on how to store)

Customer 123 for salesrep A gets 1% for the first 2 years, than .5%
Customer 456 for salesrep B gets 2% for the first 1 year, than .75%

At any given time, I have to be able get the correct percentage based on the current age of the customer.  So if customer A was created June 1 2012, commision is 2%.  If customer was created Sept 5 2008, then commission is .5%.

SOLUTION Based on Gordon Linoff's answer:

```
SET @custAgeInMonths = datediff(month, @custCreationDate, @invDate)

    --First look for a customer specific record
    SELECT @result = C.Commission
    FROM NCL_Commissions C
    WHERE C.CustCode = @custCode
    AND C.SalesRep = @salesRep
    AND ProductType in ('L')
    AND @custAgeInMonths BETWEEN C.MinAgeMonths AND C.MaxAgeMonths
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.  Also, show what you've tried, such as calculating the customer age.

Comment: why dose Customer 123 get 1% ? base on what? you said they get 2% the first 2 years

Comment: Is there always only one percentage change? For example, are there any cases along the lines of "rep X gets 3% for customer Y for the first year, 2% for the second year, and 1% after that"? Are the splits any more granular than yearly (for example, "rep X gets a commission of 1% for 6 months and .5% after that")?

Comment: @vaquito -Based on managment.  These values are given, and I have to store them in a table somehow.  I'm not sure how to best store and query them, hence the OP.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName -So far there is, I'd be satisfied with designing it with 1 percentage change.  Yearly is best I can tell, but maybe I should design for months and convert?  Although a design which could accommodate more changes is obviously prefereble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a join.

Assume you have a customer table, with the start date of the customer and the commission table above.  You can calculate the current age of the customer and join into the commission table.  This assumes that the customer record has the sales rep:

```
select <whatever>
from (select c.*, datediff(day, c.joindate, getdate())/365.25 as AgeYears
      from customer c
     ) c left outer join
     NCL_Commissions com
     on c.CustCode = com.CustCode and
        c.ProductType= com.ProductType and
        c.SalesRep = com.SalesRep and
        c.AgeYears between MinAge and c.MaxAge
```

Given all the join criteria, I would watch out for non-matches (hence the use of the left outer join).

Comment: So your suggesting I store the customer creation date?  Hmmm.

Comment: Although, isn't 365.25 more accurate for the year division?

Comment: Non matches aren't a problem, because after this piece of code executes, the selected value will be checked for null.

Comment: Although you're going to want to be careful of whether `minAge` and `maxAge` are inclusive or exclusive.  And which table are those ages in?

Comment: @X-Zero -I'm thinking of using the minage and maxage.  As far as the customer age, I could make a UDF to determine that on the fly.

Comment: @MAW74656 . . . I fixed the query to have 365.25.  I used floats for the age, which pretty much gets around the "between" issue.  However, because this is dealing with commissions, I'm guessing that the age calculation might have a political component as well as an arithmetic one.  So, the real definition might be the customer age at the beginning of the quarter, or something like that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -I suppose there is politics, but that's not my problem, I'll just insist they give me the values, not the reasons.  I think I'll use months, which will allow me to also account for quarters.

Comment: Main point making this the best answer is that you managed to explain to me my real issue.  I was wanting to store ages, but calculate based on raw dates (instead of ages).  I just couldn't see my dis-connect until your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) you need a table that has the commissions brackets (i recommend by month)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommissionsBrakets](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Commission] [Decimal](4, 4) NULL,
Month [smaillint])
```

fill it with the brakets

```
1    2%  1 /month 1 2%
1    2%  2 /month 2 2%
....
1  0.5% 24 /month 24 (2 years) 0.5%
```

2) you need a table relating costumer+salesrep+comisionBracket

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NCL_Commissions](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
[CustCode] [varchar](30) NULL,
[SalesRep] [varchar](10) NULL,
[CommissionID] [int] NULL)
```

then you can do a join

```
declare @mothDiff int = DATEDIFF(m, @custCreationDate, GETDATE())


Select b.Commission from NCL_Commissions C inner join CommissionsBrakets B 
on c.CommissionID  =   B.ID 
where 
B.month = case 
    when @mothDiff > ((select max(Month) from CommissionsBrakets CB where CB.id = B.ID   ))
    then (select max(Month) from CommissionsBrakets CB where CB.id = B.ID   )
    else @mothDiff
    end
```